# Which MySQL storage engine is the most similar to ARCHIVE when that is not available?

Tags: mysql, innodb, myisam, storage-engine

I have a table that contains a log of events that is written to often and read very infrequently by comparison.  I would love to use the [ARCHIVE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/archive-storage-engine.html) engine, because it is basically designed for exactly this.  However, this engine is not available on my hosting provider.

The only (useful) options available are MyISAM, InnoDB, and CSV.  I am pretty sure I should *not* use CSV for this option, so let's discount that one.

What I'm looking for then is the engine that provides the best alternative, keeping in mind the following:

- Good compression would be very nice.  A lot of the data may be very similar between rows (as is the case with log messages)
- I don't need a fast look up.  Indexes aren't really necessary.  Again, I'm looking to save as much space as possible.
- There needs to be support for *lots* of rows.  Hence the need for compression and small footprint.
- Rows *do* have a foreign key to another table, but it is not necessary to retain the relationship.  Each log entry has a name associated with it that is stored in the other table, which doesn't change.

So based on that, which is better, InnoDB, or MyISAM.  I know that the MyISAM engine installed on this server only supports 2^32 rows.  If InnoDB has similar support for compression and supports more rows, that would be better (but I don't know if that is the case).

Comment: Just out of curiosity: what do you want to use this for?

Comment: Session event tracking.  Whenever a user performs an action that is worthy of knowing about, an log of the event is inserted as a row in the table.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

InnoDB supports compression as of MySQL **5.1** (with InnoDB Plugin), or natively in MySQL **5.5**. The level of compression really depends on your table content, but I see 75% reduction in size as common.

Reads and writes to compressed tables involve more CPU. InnoDB will support your foreign keys as well as any indexes.

I would say it is a fairly good out-of-the-box solution for your problem.

MyISAM only supports compression on a read-only mode.

Or you might find an altogether NoSQL solution to do the job well for you, given that you don't really need indexes.

I'm a relational geek, so I would first go for InnoDB. Just:

```
ALTER TABLE my_table ENGINE=InnoDB ROW_FORMAT=COMPRESSED KEY_BLOCK_SIZE=4;
```

`KEY_BLOCK_SIZE` can be 1,4,8,16; Lower numbers will give you better compression. My experience shows that 4 gives good compression. 1 rarely improves much, and consumes a lot more CPU.